# Unsigned char goes from f0 to 00 when incremented by 16

Tags: c, char, hex, unsigned-char

I am currently writing a program in C. I have a variable `i` declared in my program. I have initialized it as such:

```
 unsigned char i = 0x00;
```

Next, I have a while loop, and inside that while loop, I'm increasing the `unsigned char` by 16 and displaying it to seven digits (such as `0000080`). Well, This runs perfectly fine for the first 16 values, but whenever the `unsigned char` gets to `00000f0` and gets incremented again, it goes back to `0000000`. Why is this and how can I alter my code to fix this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: A `char` is 8 bit long, `0xf0 + 16 = 0x100` which is greater than `0xff`, the largest value a `char` can have, so you overflow the `char` and that's why you see the 0.

Comment: use `unsigned long` instead

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An `unsigned char`, assuming 8 bit to a byte, has a maximum value of 255 (0xff).  Any arithmetic operation that exceeds that is truncated modulo 256.

If you want to support larger values, use `unsigned int` instead.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't realize chars were only 8 bits. I'll accept as soon as I can.

Comment: @MatthewVanlandingham Detail: `char` are not "only 8 bits".  `char` are usually  "8 bits". On select platforms, they are wider.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. On my particular machine, it is 8 bits :D

Comment: By the C standard `char` is *at least* 8 bits, and on many (perhaps most) platforms it is exactly 8 bits.
On some current (embedded) DSP platforms, `char` is 16 bits.
Back In The Day, on some Cray supercomputers, `char`, `short`, `int`, and `long` (this was in the days before `long long`) were *all* 64 bits, and thus `sizeof(long) == 1`.